# Terraform assign variable value using for loop if condition is true

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I need to assign short_id to variable short_location_name,

I have map short_location_names in below terrfaorm code, if "var.location" is "westus", I need to assign short_location_names "wus"

my_code:

```
locals {
  short_location_names = {
      "westus": "wus",
      "eastus": "eus",
      "westus2": "wus2",
      "eastus2": "eus2"
  }
  short_location_name = {
    for location, short_id in local.short_location_names: location == var.location ? short_location_name => short_id
  }
```

I tried above code, I getting error missing false statement, How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`lookup`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/lookup.html) function instead:

```
short_location_name = lookup(local.short_location_names, var.location, null)
```

or

```
short_location_name = { var.location: lookup(local.short_location_names, var.location, null) }
```

Or simply `local.short_location_names[var.location]` if the value will always be present in the map.

Answer (score 2):

> **Working Solution**

```
locals {
 short_location_name  = "${lookup(local.region_code, var.location, "null")}"

 region_code = {

 "East US 2" = "use2"
 "eastus2" = "use2"
 "West US 2" = "usw2"
 "westus2" = "usw2"
 
 }
}
```